# Getting issue while fetching data using Relationship in laravel7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have three table country, state, customer_contacts. I want display all customer details into list view structure. But in my customer table only id save of country and state respectively. I want to fetch Country nad state Name from other two table .
Table structure as follows :

**1. Country**

```
id  name
1  India
2  Canada
```

**2. State**

```
id  name     country_id
1  Mumbai       1
2  Delhi        1
3  abc          2
4  xyz          2
```

**3. Customer_contact**

```
id  c_name     country_id  state_id
1   abcdee       1           2
2   xyzerr       1           1
3   extraa       2           3
4   newsss       2           4
```

i want to fetch customer name with country name and state name.

I am using below query to fetch data but getting only customer_contact data how to fetch name using any query or relationship.

```
$data = CustomerContact::with('Country', 'State')->get();
```

I am using relationship as follow:

**1) Country Model**

```
<?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Country extends Model
   {

   public function state()
   {
         return $this->hasMany(State::class);
  }
  public function customercontact()
  {
       return $this->hasMany(CustomerContact::class);
  }
}
```

**2) State Model**

```
class State extends Model
{
  public function customercontact()
  { 
       return $this->hasMany(CustomerContact::class);
  }
  public function country()
  {
       return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
  }
}
```

**3) CustomerContact**

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class CustomerContact extends Model
    {
          protected $guarded = [];

       public function country()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
       }

       public function state()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
        }
  }
```

I want show data in list view like CustomerName, CountryName,StateName.
When i do
dd($data)

getting data with country and state id but relationship getting null value.

Help me in this.

Comment: I find your relations a bit strange. Costumer hasMany state, while country hasMany state!?

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani , Its a Contact form . In contact form country and state dropdown  field be there.

Comment: Ok, but i mean: customer will write contact form in one country, that is in one state. Or i missing something?

Comment: Yes right. Customer can fill the form with there details name,  country nd corresponding state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **CustomerSupport** you defined two function `country()` and `state()`, so your code will be :

```
$data = CustomerContact::with('country','state')->get();
```

Or,

```
$data = CustomerContact::with('country')->with('state')->get();
```

Comment: ,I tried this but i am getting Null value in state and country relationship

Comment: You have a typo `with('Country', 'State')` will be `with('country', 'state')`

Comment: $data = CustomerContact::with('country', 'state')->get(); i am using this . But in relationship getting NULL data.

Comment: Did you define foreign_key on your migration file correctly?

Comment: I am not getting what you want to say. In migration what need to do exact?

Comment: Can you post `customer_contact` migration file with your question?

Comment: Schema::create('customer_contacts', function(Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->text('name');
                $table->text('email');
                $table->text('phone');
                $table->text('address');
                $table->bigInteger('country_id');
               
                $table->bigInteger('state_id');
                
                $table->text('comment');
                $table->text('organization');
                $table->text('captcha');
                $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: this is the my customer_contacts migration schema

Comment: $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: Above trying for foreign key but getting issue when run migrate command

Comment: @Praful You did not define foreign key on your database

Comment: $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')->onDelete('cascade');................. I am using this also but getting error

Comment: change `$table->bigInteger('country_id');` to `$table->foreignId('country_id');` and `$table->bigInteger('state_id'); ` to `$table->foreignId('state_id');`

Comment: Can you help me in this?